# Calculating inverse of trig functions without calculator

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, inverse-function

We have $\sin 25°\approx 0.42.$  How to  calculate $\arcsin0. 42\approx 25°$ without the help of calculator? And how does calculator evaluate the inverse functions value.

Comment: why do you need it for?, what is the context? calculators have look-up table, so do not calculate. What is the first relation you wrote for? is it a known data of your problem or not?

Comment: Most calculators do calculate. See cordic and other methods. A look-up table would be too big unless interpolation used.

Comment: But In which  formula lookup table is based on to calculate the inverse so accurately?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really don't want to use a calculator, not even for divisions or multiplications, you can't use any formula, not even for two digit accuracy, doing that by hand is _very_ tedious. You could do only as we did at school in the sixties: using (printed) tables of trigonometric function values together with interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Maclauren series for arcsin:

$$\arcsin x = x+\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{3x^5}{40}+\frac{5x^7}{112} +\cdots.$$

So $\arcsin 0.42 \approx 0.43343.$  This is in radians, so convert to degrees:
$0.43343\cdot 180/\pi \approx 24.833$ degrees.

Comment: And do you know any formula to calculate log value without calculator like the same way. ??

Comment: The topic is  "Taylor series" or "Maclauren series."  If you  google "Taylor series log" you'll get plenty of hits.  If you use google images, it'll be faster. You can find lists of commonly used Taylor series.